# Reporting tool/framework/library for .Net

Tags: c#, reporting, sql, sql-server

I want to print pdf reports with lots of charts and text on demand. I have some  sub reports, which can be generated stand-alone and can also be merged to generate a single master report.

Right now, **I am using jsreport.net to achieve this with a C# application and SQL Server 2014 database. I want to know if there are better alternatives available there? with more options and possibly faster as well?? which may be free as well?**

I am looking for something, that can transform html to pdf, like jsreport and not something like crystal reports.

Comment: Please explain exactly what is wrong with jsreport.net

Comment: Nothing specifically is wrong with it and I like the features it provide. but I am looking if there are similar alternatives available.

Comment: Please explain exactly, with more details, what "better" means to you. What exact other options do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Essential Chart for JS](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/chart/line) and other controls from the Syncfusion library (or any other HTML/JS based library) can be used to create the reports. These reports can then be converted to PDF using [Essential PDF](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf)

[Example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/Sync_cjdx5cwn)

Click the Download button to convert to PDF.

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [List & Label](https://www.combit.net/reporting/highlights/). The integration into existing C# project is very easy and it's designer is really powerful. It's core is written in C++ and it's printing fast. I did not try jsreport so can't promise you it's faster, but it is definitely worth a try.

Comment: I am looking for a html based report designer like jsreport.net

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to try [Stimulsoft Reports](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/downloads). The product [Stimulsoft Reports.Ulitmate](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/products/reports-ultimate) is specifically designed for the .NET platform. WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC - everything is supported by the software. The product contains runtime designers which can be easily integrated into apps. The designers have all the features you may need to design report as complex as you want.

I work at Stimulsoft.